# C# Add Bytes to picture to increase file size

Tags: c#, file, byte, filestream

I need to equalize the file size of 2 files in C# so that both have the same size.
In this case i use pictures and I tried to add random bytes to the picture with less size,
through `FileStream.write` with an Byte[] that contains the amount of bytes I need, but the file size always stays the same.

Any tips how I can handle this?

Comment: Many image modes use compression to reduce file size.  You need to use an image mode that does not have compression.  I would not use a picture to add random data to files to make equal.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't change the Position in the Stream, and you overwrote the beginning bytes, or you changed one of the copies of the file... Or who knows? We want code AND innards here, but especially code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it now, I needed to use `File.WriteAllBytes` to get it working

Thanks for your time! :)